# tiny-mce textarea not displayed correctly with grails

Tags: grails, tinymce, grails-plugin

I have a problem using the “tiny-mce” with grails (textarea is not displayed correctly).
I’m using Eclipse Indigo and have installed the tiny-mce plugin with “grails install-plugin tiny-mce”.
The code which I have written is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>TinyMCE Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <tinyMce:resources />
    <tinyMce:importJs/>
</head>

<body>
        <tinyMce:renderEditor type="advanced"/>

</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that the textarea which is display does not have the tiny-mce features, i.e. all nice properties/buttons which can be used to format the text. The textarea is just a simple html textarea. 
It looks like the inspected generated source code (i.e. right click-> view source) might have some problems:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>TinyMCE Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/MyGrailsProject/static/plugins/tiny-mce-    3.4.9/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/MyGrailsProject/static/plugins/tiny-mce-3.4.9/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">tinyMCE.init({
                            mode : "textareas",
                            theme : "simple",
                            editor_selector : "mcesimple",
                            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "null"
                        });tinyMCE.init({
                            mode : "textareas",
                            theme : "advanced",
                            editor_selector : "mceadvanced",
                            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top"
                        });</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea class='null mceadvanced'></textarea>
</body></html>
```

It looks like the textarea class has a null value. Is this correct? Does anyone know why my textarea is not render correctly? Is the problem related to that the file “tiny_mce.js” is not found? If that’s the case, how can I fix this?

Best regards
Clay

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I got this working by doing the following:

1. Download tinymce from http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php => Gives you a file ~/tinymce
2. Copy ~/tinymce to /web-apps/js/tiny_mce
3. In main.gsp add `<g:javascript src="tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"/>` This will pick up the folder under the web-apps/js folder
4. Tiny mce still won't work at this point. It will complain about en.js and editor_template.js
5. You have to go to Config.groovy and add this line
   `grails.resources.adhoc.excludes = ['/js/tiny_mce/**/*.*']`
6. Now back to the gsp, add the tiny_mce.init() line ex

   ```
   tinyMCE.init({
       theme : "advanced",
       mode : "textareas",
       plugins : "fullpage",
       theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "fullpage"
   });
   ```

   inside `<g:javascript>` tags like

   ```
   <g:javascript>
   tinyMCE.init({
       theme : "advanced", 
       mode : "textareas",
       plugins : "fullpage",
       theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "fullpage"
   });
   </g:javascript>
   ```
7. Now add the textarea as per usual `<g:textArea name="..."/>`
8. Grails escapes html by default inside things like `${fieldValue(bean:...)}` so your beautiful tiny mce markup will be escaped
9. Change the above to `${object.field}` and ex: `${person.firstName}` and there you have it.

Answer (score 1):

The [TinyMCE Grails Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/tiny-mce) is **not** necessary, and is currently 3 months out of date.  You can instead go to [TinyMCE's site](http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php) and download the latest version there.

Extract their ZIP file and copy the folder `tinymce\jscripts\tiny_mce` into your Grails project, under the `web-app` folder.  (Take care **not** to copy it into `web-app\js` because that is managed by the [Resources](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#resources) plugin and you'd need to expose every required static resource inside `ApplicationResources.groovy`.)

Then inside your .GSP, you'd have something like this in the `<head>` section of your page:

```
<g:javascript src="../tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"/>
<r:script>
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "advanced"
    });
</r:script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler way to get it working  -  include the tinymce js in html head

```
<head>
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
        tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
</script>
</head>
```

Have a textarea element in the GSP ( 'message' is a command object with field name 'content' )

```
<textarea  rows="10" name="content" >${fieldValue(bean:message,field:'content')}</textarea>
```

This is tested in Grails 2.2 , instead of the CDN //tinymce.cachefly.net , the tinymce js file can be placed in web-app/js dir and included in GSP, in a simpler way

Answer (score 0):

“tiny_mce.js” needs to be found in order to make the editor work!
Make sure you use the right path here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use rich ui plugin for rich text editor.

Its very simple and nice.

just install ricuui plugin and

add resource in head section.

like this.

this into head section

this into body------

and enjoy......

Answer (score 0):

If you are use runtime ":resources:1.1.6" in BuildConfig.groovy than update it with
runtime ':resources:1.2'.
it's work fine for me.